# Why does CloudKit discovery return zero users on a device but multiple in the simulator?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have the same address book records on both the simulator and the device but when I run the app I get different results...

#### **In the Simulator,** Number of records returned = 3

#### **On the Device,** Number of records returned = 0

Does discovery even work on device in a production environment?

I'm new to this but need a point in the right direction.

Comment: It might help to tell us what you are doing to get those results. Update your question with some relevant code.

Comment: Are you logged in on your simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler. I already posted a bug report for it at https://bugreport.apple.com quite some time ago. By then It even got marked as duplicate. I'm not sure how consistent this behavior is in production.

In my experience the behavior on development is not consistent. It could happen that you won't get a result for hours and then suddenly it could return the wanted result. And then after that it sometimes it stops working again.

In my app I have tried to make this more stable by archiving the result if there is any and then if you don't get a result then just return the archived result. You can archive the result using a NSKeyedArchiver.

[image]

Comment: That bug report is just sad to look at

Comment: @JustSid I would be happy to look at bug report you're approve.

Comment: Well... It's now open for more than a year. The status is still that it's a duplicate of that ticket and that it's still open...